# Get position of UIAlertAction?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertaction

I like to do a tutorial that ask user have to press the 'Always Allow' button in the Location Permission request.

In my opinion, use a `ViewController` and add a `UIAlertController` as a subView in it, and then add another `CAShapeLayer` to create a white rectangle to highlight the 'Always Allow' `UIAlertAction`.

My problem is that I can't locate the 'Always Allow' `UIAlertAction`.
I need the `CGPoint` of this `UIAlertAction`. How to get it?

Update:This is not a real permission alert, I think many people misunderstanding it. In iOS, when a permission alert popup, user sometimes choose any one without reading the message on it. Because our hardware product needs location update in background, we hope user have to choose 'Always' location option, this is why do that. We want to do a guide to teach people that a alert page will display at next step and please choose the correct one. After pressing the upper right corner button, the real permission will popup. I think it's a good way to guide user.

[The Right Way To Ask Users For iOS Permissions](https://techcrunch.com/2014/04/04/the-right-way-to-ask-users-for-ios-permissions/)

Any suggestions for it? Thanks.

[image: UIAlertAction]

Comment: You will do this, so as to force the user to only select `Always Allow`?

Comment: @ShamasS Yes, because our hardware product need the the location in background. iOS 11 add a new one 'Only While Using the App', we worry about user choose the wrong option and let the app didn't work well. This is  why we do that.

Comment: In that case, you should only warn user more sternly, that they should not choose that option. Else, even if you are able to implement it, you app will most definitely get rejected.

Comment: @ShamasS Actually, this page is a guide, it's not a really permission request. When user press the upper right corner button, the real alert of system will popup. Apple will reject it?

Answer (score 1):

1. The "Allow to use location" alert is provided by the system which displays the UI in another process.
2. This is bad UX.
3. Apple will reject your app for doing this.

Comment: 1. This is not a real location permission request page. This is a guide to help user to know a page will display and please choose 'Always'. You can image it is a photo, but I want to implement it programmatically.
2. Why is it a bad UX?
3. For what reason to reject?